# Capture selected element in a TForm in design time

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I'm making a productivity tool that presents information about a form. One of its components is a TreeView that represents the hierarchy of objects inside the form.

Right now I'm able to change the selected item in the form as I change the selected node in the tree
[image: Selected item]

I'm simply using this code when the tree view selection changes:

```
procedure SeleccionarComponente(const Nombre: string);
var
  FormEditor: IOTAFormEditor;
  Componente: IOTAComponent;
begin
  // Seleccionar el componente en el editor de formularios
  FormEditor := GetCurrentFormEditor;
  Componente := FormEditor.FindComponent(Nombre);
  if Componente <> nil then
    Componente.Select(False);
end;
```

Is there a way to do it the other way? I want to change the tree view selection whenever a component is clicked on the form.

Comment: On modern Delphi versions you would use [IDesigner](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/DesignIntf.IDesigner) interface to retrieve state of Form designer or interact with it programmatically. But I don't how that could be achieved in Delphi 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was quite trivial, in the end.

My form inherits from `TDesignWindow`:

```
TVentanaVisorComponentes = class(TDesignWindow)
```

So I can override some methods

```
procedure ItemDeleted(const ADesigner: IDesigner; AItem: TPersistent); override;
procedure ItemsModified(const ADesigner: IDesigner); override;
procedure ItemInserted(const ADesigner: IDesigner; Item: TPersistent); override;
procedure SelectionChanged(const ADesigner: IDesigner; const ASelection: IDesignerSelections); override;
procedure DesignerClosed(const ADesigner: IDesigner; AGoingDormant: Boolean); override;
```

The method SelectionChanged did the trick

```
procedure TVentanaVisorComponentes.SelectionChanged(
  const ADesigner: IDesigner; const ASelection: IDesignerSelections);
var
  NuevaSeleccion: TNodoArbolComponentes;
begin
  inherited;
  if (ASelection.Count = 1) and (ASelection.Items[0] is TComponent) then
  begin
    NuevaSeleccion := BuscarNodoPorComponente(ASelection.Items[0] as TComponent);
    if NuevaSeleccion <> nil then
      TreeView1.Selected := NuevaSeleccion;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write a class that implements the [`IDesignNotification`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/DesignIntf.IDesignNotification) interface, and then register an instance of that class with the IDE using the [`RegisterDesignNotification()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/DesignIntf.RegisterDesignNotification) function. The [`IDesignNotification.SelectionChanged()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/DesignIntf.IDesignNotification.SelectionChanged) method is what you are looking for.

> Called when the selected components on a form designer change.